# Linearized operator of higher order $p$ Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, p-laplace

The $p$th Laplacian is defined as $-\Delta_pv= \text{div}(|Dv|^{p−2}|Dv|)$. My question is whether there are any analogous notions of $p$th $m$-Laplacian for $m$ even and odd. For the $p$th bi-Laplacian, I know this exists and it is $-\Delta^{2}_{p}v=\Delta(|\Delta v|^{p-2}|\Delta v|)$. But are there any general forms of $p$th higher-order Laplacian for $m$ even and odd?

If yes, I know the linearized $p$th Laplacian operator is $L_v(\phi)= -\text{div}(|Dv|^{p−2}|D\phi| + (p − 2)|Dv|^{p−4}|(Dv \cdot D\phi)Dv)$. This involves somewhat substantial calculation. However, for higher-order $p$ th Laplacian, even for the bi-Laplacian, is there any easy form of the linearized operator like for the $p$ th Laplacian case? Any help is very much appreciated. The final answer is fine; I will check the calculations accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's maybe a more revealing way to write the linearization of the p-Laplacian:
$$L_v(\phi) = -\text{div}(|Dv|^{p - 2}\mathscr{C} D\phi)$$
where we define the rank-4 tensor
$$\mathscr{C} = I + (p - 2)\frac{Dv\otimes Dv}{|Dv|^2},$$
which is dimensionless.
This is worth meditating on.
I prefer writing it this way because it makes it obvious that the linearization is a divergence-form elliptic operator and is therefore symmetric and positive-definite.

To answer your question about generalizing the p-Laplace equation, I think the most helpful way to write the PDE is to instead pose it as minimizing the functional
$$J(v) = \int_\Omega\left(\frac{1}{p}|Dv|^p - fv\right)dx.$$
But here we could replace $D$ by any differential operator $L$, for example the Laplace operator $\Delta$ or something of even higher order.
In that case the Euler-Lagrange equations become
$$L^*\left(|Lv|^{p - 2}Lv\right) = f$$
where $L^*$ is the adjoint of $L$.
In the case where $L$ is the gradient, $L^*$ is $-\text{div}$.
You may need other terms depending on boundary conditions and such.